# Find the integral closure of an integral domain in its field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and let $R = k[x,y]/(x^2-y^2+y^3)$. Note that $R$ is an integral domain. Let $F$ be the field of fractions of $R$. How to determine the integral closure of $R$ in $F$?

I have no idea how this integral closure looks like. But I find that $F = k(\overline{x}/\overline{y})$, because $\overline{y} = -(\overline{x}/\overline{y})^2 + 1$ and hence $\overline{x} = -(\overline{x}/\overline{y})^3 + (\overline{x}/\overline{y})$.

Also, a general method for find the integral closure of an integral domain in its field of fractions is strongly desirable. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can uses a parametrization of $x^2-y^2+y^3=0$: $x=t^3-t$, and $y=1-t^2$. This shows that $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^2+y^3)\simeq k[t^3-t,t^2-1]$. But the integral closure of $k[t^3-t,t^2-1]$ is $k[t]$, so you can conclude that the integral closure of $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^2+y^3)$ is *isomorphic* to $k[t]$ (or, if you like, equals $k[x/y]$).

Comment: Could you please explain why the integral closure of $k[t^3-t,t^2-1]$ is $k[t]$? I can only see that $k[t]$ is contained in its integral closure. BTW, do you have any reference for the method of parametrization? Thank you very much.

Comment: The ring extension $k[t^3-t,t^2-1]\subset k[t]$ is integral, both rings have the same field of fractions, that is, $k(t)$ and $k[t]$ is integrally closed.

Comment: Vakil's book on the foundations of algebraic geometry gives plenty of examples of parametrizations.

Comment: Do you mean this one?http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf